# What did Jon Arryn mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, game-of-thrones

So in *Game Of Thrones* Grand Maester Pycelle says to Eddard that Jon Arryn was rambling a lot before he died but he kept repeating "The seed is strong."
Now I have seen all four seasons all the way through and I still don't know what it means. Lysa Arryn says that he was talking about Robin but she is pretty crazy so I'm just wondering if I have missed something or if it is explained in the books.

Comment: "Duplicate" of [this question on the SF&F SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-seed-is-strong). ;-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the the first series Eddard Stark discovers that

> Cersei's children are not king Robert's, but Jamie's.

He does this by using the same book that Jon Arryn uses to research the genealogy of the Baratheons through the ages.

Eddard discovers that every Baratheon child for centuries has black hair. This is proven when he searches out all of King Robert's bastards and finds that they too have black hair.

The reason he finds this out is because he's following Jon Arryn's footsteps before he died, so we can conclude that Jon Arryn discovered the same secret and was murdered for it.

Genealogically, people tend to have certain traits because certain characteristics of a human are more likely to occur because of dominant genes.

However before scientific breakthroughs people would have assumed it's because of the person, rather than the genes themselves, why this occurred.

So when Jon Arryn was repeating "The seed is strong", he was trying to reveal the secret he had discovered before he died.

In the throes of death when he was poisoned he wouldn't have been able to give a full description about his findings, so he hoped that someone would understand from these words what he had found. Which Eddard eventually did.

Comment: That wraps it all up nice and tidy, have my upvote !

Comment: +1 Just to be specific: we **could** conclude that Jon Arryn was murdered for his secret until in season 4 we found out what was the real reason of his death.

Comment: Little Finger killed him not the Lannisters @Hegemon.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani My comment wasn't a question or a riddle :-) I wrote it this way to avoid spoiling for people who didn't watch season 4 yet.

Comment: But I was thinking about something else, which in fact will result in spoilers so better remain quiet.

Comment: I still don't get why he was saying "the seed is strong" how was that supposed to indicate that Joffrey wasn't a Baratheon? Is it because all Baratheons are strong?

Comment: In modern times, Jon Arryn might say "the trait is dominant" :)

Comment: @MatthewStevenson Although this is the most plausible explanation, there's an alternate one. Princess Rhaenyra married Laenor Velaryon. She however had an extra-marital affair with Ser [Harwin Strong](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harwin_Strong). Her first three "Velaryon" Children were rumored to be sired by Ser Harwin as they lacked the Valyrian silver hair, aquiline nose, Blue-ish eyes despite the supposed parents both being Valyrian. So "Seed is Strong" could be pointing to that, Strong a reference to the Strong family. Just like Laenor was cuckolded, so was Robert.

Comment: @IMil - Or "the dominant alleles show a high degree of penetrance."  :D

Comment: @ChanandlerBong - that might **still** be the reason, with Littlefinger manipulating Lysa to make her think otherwise.  Or some degree of both.  I guess we'll have to wait for the final episode of the series when Bran does his omniscient "Scooby Doo" wrap-up explanation of everything they weren't able to tie-off, despite obvious forced pacing of the final two seasons.

Comment: @Aegon - that would be quite a contortion, unless Robert were somehow cuckholded by a member of the Strong clan.

Comment: @MatthewStevenson - "Seed is strong" = "Robert's physical traits dominate in all his offspring, regardless of what the mother looks like."  So, those three kids all have dominant Lannister characteristics, and none of the dark hair, etc that every single one of his bastards do, indicating that they are not his.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Strongs are all dead, like many of the families who have held Harrenhal after conquest. If "Ossifer Plumm's six feet member" can pass into Westerosi proverbs, I don't see how Strong story shouldn't. You seem to have ignored the "this is the most plausible explanation" part.

Answer (score 1):

He's talking about the Baratheon seed. It's strong so all Baratheons have black hair, regardless of who they breed with. All of Robert's bastards have black hair. All Baratheons going back years have black hair. Since the seed is strong, Robert's "children" by Cersei couldn't possibly be his, because they have blonde hair.